# 'XElement' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Xml.Linq' appears in vb project and not in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have vs 2010, 32 OS machine, max framework 4.0;

I have created an empty website in C# language and I have added below DLLs to it:

- Newtonsoft.Json.dll version 11.0.1
- RestSharp.Net2.dll version 1.1.11
- Another dll created by another company to use it as an API which depends on above dlls;

I have added references to those dlls and used there objects... When I run the website --> it runs successfully and results are returned as expected;

When I do the same in VB (by creating a new empty website and adding dlls in its bin folder then reference to them) --> I can use there objects but multiple errors are thrown in compilation, example:

> Error    1   'XElement' is ambiguous in the namespace
>   'System.Xml.Linq'.    InternalXmlHelper.vb
>       Error 3   'XName' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Xml.Linq'.    InternalXmlHelper.vb
>       Error 7   'XAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Xml.Linq'.   InternalXmlHelper.vb
>   ....

What can be the problem?

**Update**
I discovered that whenever I remove reference to RestSharp dll, errors won't be shown on built, but if I run the code --> errors are shown because APIs are using this library as you can see [image: Here].

VB code:

```vb
Imports CompanyX.Api
Imports CompanyX.Client
Imports CompanyX.Model

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
        Configuration.SetApiKey("OurKey")
        Configuration.SetTest()
        Dim api As New JobsApi()
        Dim key As New JobKey()
        key.Id = "KeyID"
        Dim Job = api.GetJob(key.Id)
        Dim response = Job.ToString()    
    End Sub
End Class
```

C# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using CompanyX.Api;
using CompanyX.Client;
using CompanyX.Model;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Configuration.SetApiKey("OurKey");
        Configuration.SetTest();    
        JobsApi api = new JobsApi();
        JobKey key = new JobKey();
        key.Id = "KeyID";    
        Job job = api.GetJob(key.Id);
        String response = job.ToString();    
    }
}
```

I have tried to add `Imports System.Linq` in VB solution but still not working.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe82132c-196a-4813-a549-e2975fabe673/compiler-error-message-bc30560-xelement-is-ambiguous-in-the-namespace-systemxmllinq?forum=lightswitch

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - it will make it *much* easier to help you. (I'd also strongly recommend putting time into updating past .NET 4.0 - I don't know whether that's even getting security updates any more...)

Comment: @GSerg thank you for your reply, whenever I remove RestSharp.Net2.dll reference error, website is built successfully, but error is thrown whenever I run the website, as this library is a dependency for the API, so what can I do? Please check my update

Comment: RestSharp.Net2 sounds like it's designed to be used in .NET 2.0, not .NET 4.0. My guess is that it's got a bunch of LINQ to XML classes in there as well. Have you tried using a more recent version of RestSharp?

Comment: Further evidence of that: https://github.com/mcintyre321/RestSharp-.NET-2.0-Fork

Comment: That's why you're running into problems: there are two versions of LINQ to XML present. That's not going to go well.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for your reply it is the first time I deal with this DLL I will try to upgrade the version and revert back to you, but why it is running on C# webSite with framework 4.0?

Comment: I'd need to see the working C# code and the broken VB code know, basically - you still haven't provided a [mcve]. But as I said before, I'd strongly recommend that you update to a more recent version of the framework anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet please check my edit; Please note that this is the maximum framework number for a 32 bit machine;

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't include `XElement` at all - I can't see how you'd get that compiler error from that code. But as far as I can see there *are* later versions of .NET that support x86 - see https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42642 for example.

Comment: Or indeed https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56116 (Look at the list of supported operating systems.)

Comment: @JonSkeet The MCVE is a freshly created VB.NET console project that has the `RestSharp.Net2` nuget package installed. Fails to compile straight away even with FW 4.7.1.

Comment: @GSerg: The code provided here isn't a console project - it's inheriting from `System.Web.UI.Page`, and importing `CompanyX.Api` which we don't appear to have any code for. In other words, it's not a *complete* example to start with. And with a later version of the framework, you then wouldn't use RestSharp.Net2 - you'd just use RestSharp, at which point the problem would go away because there wouldn't be the embedded LINQ to XML implementation.

Comment: @JonSkeet What I'm saying is that I was able to reproduce the OP's error messages simply by creating an empty VB.NET project and installing the nuget package.

Comment: @GSerg: Ah, that's a somewhat different matter, but it's good to know. I still think the best way for the OP to proceed is to move away from an unsupported framework and start using the regular RestSharp library though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Jon Skeet explained in the comments above,

- **Why does it fail to compile?**

  Because the [`RestSharp.Net2` package](https://github.com/mcintyre321/RestSharp-.NET-2.0-Fork) contains [its own implementation of `System.Linq.Xml`](https://github.com/mcintyre321/RestSharp-.NET-2.0-Fork/tree/master/RestSharp.Net2/System.Xml.Linq) which conflicts with the `System.Linq.Xml` implementation from the .NET Framework 4.0. You cannot have two implementations of the same thing.
- **But why is that even a thing?**

  Because the package is supposed to be used with .NET Framework 2 that does not come with an implementation of `System.Linq.Xml`. That is why the package bothers to provide one in the first place.
- **But why does it work with C#?**

  Because unlike VB, C# does not try to use `System.Linq.Xml` on its own.

  VB has [much fancier support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/xml-literals-overview) for XML which comes with the `InternalXmlHelper.vb` module that you cannot get rid of and that causes the error because it tries to use the `System.Linq.Xml` namespace.

  You will get a compilation error in C# too if you make use of e.g. `XElement`. Simply adding `System.Xml.Linq.XElement x = null;` to the C# code is enough to cause

  > Error    CS0433
  >   The type 'XElement' exists in both 'RestSharp.Net2, Version=102.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
- **So what do I do?**

  Either:

  - Switch to a version of the package that is designed for more recent versions of .NET Framework and thus does not provide a conflicting implementation of built-in functionality
  - Downgrade your project to FW 2.0 for which the package was designed